# Unkown error involving templates

Tags: c++, templates

This code is in a header file and the header file by itself can compile just fine. The idea is this is a BST and I am supposed to create an iterator that will iterate through it in order.

I think I have this figured out just fine but I must have the wrong syntax for the functions. They compile without given a type but when given a type such as `int` it says it can't find a version with `int`, etc.

```
template <class TKey>
class bst {
  private:
    struct node {
      node() { key=TKey(); link[0]=link[1]=NULL; parent=NULL; }
      operator TKey () { return key; }
      void print();

      TKey key;
      node *link[2];
      node *parent;
    };

  public:
    class iterator {
    public:
    private:
      friend class bst<TKey>;
      node *p;
    };
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

    TKey operator*(iterator rhs){return rhs.p -> key;}
    bool operator!=(iterator rhs) {return (!(this.p->key==rhs.p->key));}

    void operator++();

    bst() { Troot=NULL; }
    ~bst() { clear(Troot); }

    bool test;

    bool empty() { return Troot==NULL; }
    void clear() { clear(Troot); Troot=NULL; }

    node *prev_node;
    void erase(TKey &key);
    void insert(TKey &key);

    void print_inorder() { print_inorder(Troot); }
    void print_bylevel();
    void print_iterator();

  private:
    void clear(node *);

    node *minmax_key(node *, int);
    node *erase(node *, TKey &);
    node *insert(node *, TKey &);

    void print_inorder(node *);

    node *Troot;
};
```

That was the class definition.

```
template <class  TKey>
class bst<TKey>::iterator bst<TKey>::begin(){
    node *temp = Troot;
    while(temp -> link[0])
        temp = link[0];
    cout << temp -> key << endl;

    iterator it;
    it.p = temp;
    return it;
};

template <class TKey>
class bst<TKey>::iterator bst<TKey>::end(){
    iterator it;
    it.p = NULL;
    return it;
};
```

These are the Iterator functions that seem to be causing the problems.

```
bst.h:266:2: error: no match for 'operator!=' in 'it != bst<TKey>::end [with TKey = int]()'

bst.h:266:2: note: candidates are:
```

and lists a ton of candidates

then

```
bst.h:269:3: error: no match for 'operator++' in '++it'

bst.h: In member function 'bst<TKey>::iterator bst<TKey>::begin() [with TKey = int]':

bst.h:265:22:   instantiated from 'void bst<TKey>::print_iterator() [with TKey = int]'

BST_usage1.cpp:33:19:   instantiated from here

bst.h:70:3: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]

bst.h:70:3: error: cannot convert 'int(const char*, const char*)throw ()' to 'bst<int>::node*' in assignment
```

Comment: Don't you think it would help to show  the actual error message, line of code occurring, etc?

Comment: well it spits out a monster of an error message. I figured it would just be something syntax wise with the functions I listed. Ill add the error though

Comment: Why do your operator methods take a iterator as a parameter?  That does not look right.  Also, you did not show the code in bst_usage1.cpp, so we cannot see the declaration.  Going to bed now.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `operator!=` is in class `bst<T>`, not in the inner class `bst<T>::iterator`. So you're defining an operator that takes a `bst<T>` on the left hand side, and a `bst<T>::iterator` on the right.

If you move your operator definitions inside your inner `iterator` class, you should find it works correctly (or at least gives a more helpful error message).

Comment: Thanks That makes sense. These things are always obvious once pointed out